# Do I need to clear Byte[]?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

In my game user can choose multiple images from gallery and load them into game. I have created a function that get images from filepath. In that function I declare local variable byte[]. so after read file do i need to dispose that byte[] to freed memory. here is my code :

```
if (File.Exists(filePath)) 
{
    byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    tex.LoadImage(fileData);
}
```

Do I need to clear byte[] after texture is loaded from byte[] ???? User can choose any image file from gallery so there is no limit of filesize.

Comment: `Do I need to clear byte[] after texture is loaded from byte[]` No.

Comment: Since `byte[]` *doesn't implement* `IDisposable` you *don't have* to `Dispose` (Clear, Release, Free etc.) it. Memory allocated by `byte[]` will be released by *Garbage Collector* (GC).

Comment: `so there is no limit of filesize` .. yes there is .. an array by default can maximum have `int.MaxValue` elements ;) so if the around 2GB don't fill your device's memmory anyway latest `c#` itself has a problem with it ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

`byte[]` is a managed resource. It will be fully cleaned up by the GC.

File related classes often involve unmanaged resources - usually the OS filehandles. But `File.ReadAllBytes(string)` looks like it follows my advise "create, use, dispose. All in the same piece of code, ideally using a using statement." So I expect not issues form it.

Networking and DB classes involve unamanged resources - usually network connections.

A lot of drawing related classes use unmanaged resources - primarily some unmanaged memory for performance.

But this is just a byte[]. As managed as any int[]. Note that you do not have a choice on the mater anyway as neither [byte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte?view=net-5.0) nor [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array?view=net-5.0) implement IDisposeable. If you try to dispose if it, the compiler will wonder what you are talking about as there is no such function.

Comment: Okk so there  is no need to call GC.Collect():  either right ???

Comment: @Jaimin You should never call `GC.Collect()` in production code. It is for bugfixing, not producive code. | If you are having issues with human noticable GC caused delays, change the GC mode - do not go around manually collecting.

Comment: `You should never call GC.Collect() in production code.` That is overly simplistic. It would be more accurate to say "it is incredibly rare that calling `GC.Collect` is a good idea". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/when-to-call-gc-collect

Comment: @mjwills If you have to call `GC.Collect()` there are three options: 1. You are doing bugfixing. 2. You got the wrong GC mode selected to begin with. 3. You are doing realtime programming, and a GC memory management approach is the wrong starting point for that. | If I see it, it is a bodge job at best.

Comment: I'll let you take that up with Rico @Christopher. Is it _possible_ you know more about the issue than him? Sure. Is it _likely_? Well...